# How can I get each th and following td pair on a new line within the same tr?

Tags: css, webkit

I have the following HTML structure (which I can't change unfortunately):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <td>foo</td>
            <th>Address:</th>
            <td>bar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <td>foobaz</td>
            <th>Address:</th>
            <td>barbaz</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Do note that the number of `th`/`td` pairs can vary, but within one table they are stable.

And I'm trying to use CSS to get on each line a pair of a `<th>` and a `<td>` so that the above HTML would render as:

```
Name:    foo
Address: bar

Name:    foobaz
Address: barbaz
```

I tried the following CSS to let the `<th>` to `float:left`.

```css
th {
    color:red;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
```

And similar effort for the `td`:

```css
td {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    color:green;
    position:relative;
}
```

But I assume some über-CSS-table-cell-rule is stronger than the rules I try to apply.

**Which CSS-rule(s) do I need to apply to achieve the desired rendering?**

I'm using this in the context of a webkit-engine, so I'm open for [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)-only CSS-rules.

You can find [a JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/m2sr7/1/).

Comment: Can we assume that you always have 4 elements in a row (2 `th`s and 2 `td`s)?

Comment: @ProgramFOX No, sorry, you can't :(

Comment: It is rather broad and your question is better received if you give it a try and share with us what you have so we can help out fixing an actual problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the table to no longer render as a table but as a regular block element. With some floating and clearing, it's possible to achieve a result similar to what you want. Add pseudo-selectors to set margins and you're there.

The `th:first-child + td` line is a way to use `nth-child` in IE 8

```
table, tr, th, td
{
    display: block;
}

th
{
    color: red;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}

td
{
    float: left;
    color: green;
}

th:first-child, th:first-child + td
{
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m2sr7/7/

Answer (score 4):

If you float the `<th>`, you can use clear:left to break it all up into separte lines:

```
th {
    color:red;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    position:relative;
    display:block; 
}
td {
    display:block; 
    float:left;
    color:green;
}
td:last-child {
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

I've added some extra bottom padding to create the blank line

here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2sr7/6/)

Comment: If I add a width:200px to the th and a text-align:left on both the th and td am I still good to go? It looks OK in your fiddle but I'm not sure if I overlook other issues in that case.

Comment: Nope, that shouldn't be a problem in this setup